# Why won't my variable from a previous viewController show in my labelText

Tags: ios, swift, string, textview

I'm new to Swift/Xcode and I have previous knowledge since I know other programming languages, I tried to set a textLabel in my view to be:

```
emailLabel.text = "What's your email, " + firstName + "?"
```

that showed the 'What's your email' part of the text but not the firstName variable. So I tried this:

```
emailLabel.text = "What's your email, \(firstName)?"
```

That didn’t work either, I know the variable has the right value in it as I got it to print out the variable while running the app. I have no clue why it's not showing the variable in the textField and only showing the first part of the text. Any help?

Yes, the textField is big enough to fit a very long variable in it too, so it's not like there's not enough space to show it. I even was able to just show the variable in the textField  by using this code:

```
emailLabel.text = firstName
```

and sure enough, it showed the correct variable.

I'm performing a Segue from a previous view Controller to get the user's first name, then in the second viewController the app asks for their password. I send the firstName variable through the segue and then store that variable in my viewcontroller as normal, I know the variable is getting to the second viewcontroller as I print out the value and it returns the users input:

```
import UIKit

class SignupEmailViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailInputField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UITextView!

    var firstName = ""
    var surname = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.emailInputField.delegate = self
        emailInputField.underlined()

        print(firstName)
        let emailText = "What’s your email, " + firstName + "?"
        emailLabel.text = emailText
    }
```

Nothing works.

Whole code:

```
import UIKit

class SignupEmailViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailInputField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UITextView!

    var firstName = ""
    var surname = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.emailInputField.delegate = self
        emailInputField.underlined()

        print(firstName)
        emailLabel.text = "What’s your email, " + firstName + "?"
    }

    @IBAction func next_pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do in the prepare for Segue?

Comment: And also, whenever you are logging for some value, like print(firstName), please make sure to add some identifiable string to understand where you are logging this from. Like print("value in SignUpEmailController: \(firstName)")

Comment: Why have you shown nearly identical code twice?